# RichFaces 3.3: Calling actionListener on window.onload

Tags: java, javascript, jsf, richfaces

I'd like to call an `ActionListener` and rerender some parts of my page when the page has been loaded (`window.onload`). How can I do this?

---

I can't edit the `body` tag. I've got a portlet inside a portal server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`<a4j:jsFunction>`](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_3_3_X/en/devguide/html/a4j_jsFunction.html).

```html
<h:form>
    <a4j:jsFunction name="init" actionListener="#{bean.init}" reRender="some" />
</h:form>
<script>window.onload = init;</script>
```

Comment: I can't edit the `body` tag. I'm a portlet inside a portal server.

Comment: Then use `window.onload` in a `<script>` which is placed after the `<a4j:jsFunction>`. I updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
<h:form>
    <a4j:jsFunction name="doSome" actionListener="#{bean.init}" reRender="some" />
</h:form>

<jsfc:verbatim>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        window.onload = doSome();
    </script>
</jsfc:verbatim>
```